# Compile c++ using -c

Tags: c++, compilation, codeblocks

I have a simple example to test my IDE, to get ready my C++ environment.
I'm currently using Codeblocks 13.12 in Ubuntu 14.04.

When I build my program, the compiler executes the following code, and the program will throw an error when running.

```
g++-4.8 -Wall -fexceptions -O3 -pedantic-errors -std=c++11 -Wextra -Wall -pthread  -c /home/mikeldi/workspace/codeblocks/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o
g++-4.8  -o bin/Debug/test obj/Debug/main.o
```

ERROR:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
what(): Unknown error -1
Aborted (core dumped)
```

In the other hand, if I execute the following line (note that I don't use -c before main.cpp) the program will execute without any problem.

```
g++-4.8 -Wall -fexceptions -O3 -pedantic-errors -std=c++11 -Wextra -Wall -pthread main.cpp  -o main
```

So, my question is:
What does the -c do that makes the program not work?
Is there any way of setting codeBlocks so it doesn't use -c?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: There are lots of other differences in the command lines which are more likely contenders for your problem - e.g. in the non-working one you're overriding the architecture (-march). `-c` is not your problem; it just splits compilation and linking into two separate steps.

Comment: You've obsessed over one particular flag then decided that flag _must_ be avoided. On the contrary, you _do_ want it and it likely has nothing to do with this problem. Reproduce the problem with a _minimal testcase_ that you show us here.

Comment: It's more likely the fact that one has `-fexceptions` and the other does not , especially since the crash message involved exceptions (or the arch override as Alan said).

Comment: I updated both commands so the only difference is the -c
Still the same problem
any Ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Are the two versions actually compiling the same file? (The paths are different.) Are you sure you're running the right binaries? (Again, you're using different names.)

Comment: @magodiez I'm pretty sure both calls to `g++` need `-pthread`. It has an effect on both the compiler and linker, so you probably need to include it with both calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As PeterT said in the comment, both the compiler and the linker need -pthread
once that solved, the program worked fine:

```
g++-4.8 -Wall -fexceptions -O3 -pedantic-errors -std=c++11 -Wextra -Wall -pthread  -c /home/mikeldi/workspace/codeblocks/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o
g++-4.8  -o bin/Debug/test obj/Debug/main.o -pthread
```

Thank you everybody.

Answer (score 0):

If your program throws an error at runtime, the problem is much more likely to be **in your code** than in the compiler switches you're using.  With that said, there are much more significant differences between the two compiler invocations than `-c`.  In particular, the differences are

```
-fexceptions -march=corei7  -g
```

If you add those compile switches to your command-line invocation, as with

```
g++-4.8 -fexceptions -march=corei7 -g -O3 -pedantic-errors -std=c++11
    -Wextra -Wall -pthread main.cpp -o main
```

you can recompile your code and see that it probably still crashes.  Find out where by stepping through your code using the debugger of your choice, since the `-g` flag tells the compiler to include debugging information into the generated object file.